# Query user who modified record in past

Tags: soql

I have a requirement that I have to query updated Account fields (name, type, customfields) by user whose Userlicense is 'Partner community'. I have written a query but it is not working.

```
SELECT account.name,account.type,AccountId,NewValue,OldValue,Account.Lastmodifiedby.Profile.UserLicenseId FROM AccountHistory WHERE Account.Lastmodifiedby.Profile.UserLicenseId IN ('100A0000000IUDcIAO','100A0000000IUaTIAW') and field in ('name','Type') limit 1
```

By this I am getting the partner community user but only if he last modified the records. I want the records that is been modified by him ever not the lastmodified.

Comment: Do you have Field History Tracking turned on for those fields?

Comment: Not for all fields but for some filed I have. How to fetch from it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your query is using the wrong objects, especially if you're attempting to query information related to a Partner Community User. I recommend you look at the [Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_concepts.htm) and base your query on the User Object. You can then use conditions like `WHERE User.isPartner = true`.

`LastModifiedBy` is a polymorphic field that points to `User`. You're not going to get `Lastmodifiedby.Profile.UserLicenseId` returned from the `History` object. If anything, simply knowing the User is a Partner User is all you'll need in order to return a record modified by a Partner User.

Once you have that, if you need to know their specific profile, you can run an additional query on the results to return a map of UserId to either Profile Name or ProfileId, but you're not going to get that as part of a single query as it's currently written since the data doesn't exist in that form.

Also, you don't need to run this query on Account History. You can simply run it on Account and use `WHERE LastModifiedDate <= System.NOW()`.